# Finitizing infinite comint output

Tags: process, comint

## Context

I'm a teacher and I often want to show “bad” programs; in this case infinite outputting programs.

But while I want to **show** the bad I dont want my laptop **crashing** in class (nowadays on zoom)

## The Emacs-Comint context

Comint processes can have large/indefinite/infinite output.
The commit buffer inevitably gets messed up with this

It would be good to have a minor-mode/hook for/in comint that finitizes the output in some configurable fashion.

Lets say the minor-mode is `comint-finitize-output` (cfo) having eg the following customizations

- `cfo-max-lines` default 30
- `cfo-max-chars` default 1000

So if the comint process spews out more than 30 lines or 1000 chars (whichever comes earlier)

- the display stops with a message (customizable)
- the process is interrupted with a sigint also customizable

Yeah I know about `comint-preoutput-filter-functions`

Problem is that since the output coming down the comint pipe is indeterminate in length, on account of things like

- Relative speeds of Emacs vs inferior process
- OS load

putting the above logic simplistically in a
comint-preoutput-filter-function will not work

Ideally if emacs could detect the state of the comint process to

- waiting (at prompt)
- thinking (ie computing) which if long enough signifies an infinite loop
- outputting which if long enough signifies infinite output.

Then it (emacs) could act accordingly.

But I strongly suspect that foolproof detecting this is tantamount to solving the halting problem!!  So an approximate solution is good enough!

OTOH this seems a sufficiently common facet of comint usage that I'm sure there are hacky solutions around eg that use timers to guess whether two separately received batches of text are actually from the same REPL call. Maybe something more sophisticated is possible... Dunno

Does anyone know have something like this?

---

## Examples

Of course in the most general case this is an infinite output problem and not specific to emacs.

I just thought I'd collect a slew of specific samples — C, Python, Shell and Haskell — to indicate that the problem is ideally solved at the Emacs end.
And then the statistics for each.

In a sense it just shows how clumsy I am at `C-c C-c`
What it doesn't show is how much my old creaky laptop whirrs and grumbles at the large output!
At least inside emacs it would sure help if emacs could help automate so to say my `C-c C-c`

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0;1; i++)
    printf("%d ", i);

}
```

### Python

```python
def nats():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

for i in nats():
    print(i, end = " ")
```

### Shell

```
i=0
while true; do
    printf "%d " $i
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

### Haskell (at ghci)

```haskell
[1..]
```

## My current speeds

Note

- Bigger is worse; I would like to stop at (say) 1000 chars or 30 lines
- The shell outside emacs is not really relevant; just here for completeness

1. C in emacs shell : 9,230
2. C in outside shell (gnome-shell) : 1,561,605 (and my machine starts whirring and grumbling!)
3. Python at outside shell : 360,000
4. Python in inferior python 12,770
5. Shell script at shell : 1,123
6. Shell script in emacs shell : 2,067
7. Haskell ghci : 10,042

Comment: Just pipe the output through `head` when you're running each program?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, that's right.  Well, I'm not sure how you're going to achieve this.  To my mind, either you limit the output outside of Emacs (in which case you limit the entire session), or you use Emacs process filters (which doesn't limit the amount of output being generated, and which you've said you don't want to do).

Comment: In that case, perhaps just compare `comint-last-prompt` with the `process-mark` for the process, and use `comint-interrupt-subjob` if it's too large? (As well as excluding the excess output, as appropriate.)

Comment: @phils (Please excuse deletes it's to keep SE quiet about "avoid extended discussions ). So are you suggesting putting it on output-filters or preoutput-filters?